# How to implement displayed LaTeX format data on Android devices

Tags: formatting, letters, android

I'm working on a study that implements displayed format data on Android devices and it's original source code is written in LaTeX format. I'm puzzled.

Although there have been Android software for such function, I don't know how to achieve that as I don't understand the principle. Would anyone tell or instruct me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Do I understand you correct that you need a latex editor for your android device? How much do you understand about latex?

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is not easy to respond, is your problem the installation on such a device or how to get a PDF file from the LaTeX source code to be displayed later?